# Batch effects in survival data

Tags: r, survival, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have a problem concerning batch effects in survival data of C.elegans.
I read through a few forum posts and a paper but I am still not really getting it.
In the experiment the effect of different interventions of lifespan were tested in different batches. The experiments were conducted on different dates in a machine which automatically captures the time of death. The problem is, that the temperature in each batch can not be controlled 100% and C.elegans is quite sensitive to changes in temperature.
In the end I wanna put all the data of the batches together and fit a Gompertz function to them.
My data has the following from:

Batch/ Temp/ Time_of_death

1     20       1.5

1     20       1.7

1     20       1.9

1     20       1.4

2     20       1.3

2     20       1.2

2     20       1.6

2     20       1.7
.      .         .
.      .         .
.      .         .

I know about the R function Combat but I am not sure how I would implement my data into it to get rid of batch effects and what the batch covariates exactly are.
Any Help would be very much appreciated.